# Google Sheets. Работа с датой

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, excel-формулы

У меня реализована логика: если дата в строке меньше текущей даты, то к дате в строке прибавляется месяц.

```
=ЕСЛИ(A61<>"";ЕСЛИ(ДАТА(ГОД($A$2); МЕСЯЦ($A$2); A61) < $A$2; ДАТА(ГОД($A$2); МЕСЯЦ($A$2) + 1; A61); ДАТА(ГОД($A$2); МЕСЯЦ($A$2); A61)); "")
```

Я бы хотел расширить данную формулу, чтобы учитывать год, количество дней в месяце. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Нужно к дате добавить количество дней? Опишите задачу.

Comment: @vikttur 
1) Если дата в строке меньше текущей даты, то прибавляем месяц. Если новый месяц больше 12, то прибавляем год и указываем 1 месяц года
2) Если день даты в строке равен 31, а в новом месяце дней меньше, то указываем последнее число месяца

Comment: Непонятно... Не описывайте формулу, которая есть. Опишите ЗАДАЧУ, которую решаете. Еще лучше, если покажете пример. \\\ п.1. Например, 01.01.22 меньше текущей даты, увеличиваем дату на месяц - 01.02.22 \\\ п.2. Если в месяце меньше 31 дня (например, февраль), то дата в ячейке А2 может быть 03.03.22, но  никак не 31.02.22. Не может отображаться ДАТА, которой нет в календаре. Может, если записана текстом, но это уже не дата, а текст \\\ Нужно к дате добавить указанное число дней - вот и вся задача?